# How can i resend session cookie with angular?

Tags: laravel, api

we have api buildet with laravel and we use JWT to securse our api,we send each request with set cookie and head but in front we use angular we have problem to send this cookie with diferent domaine name.
need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never set a cookie on a different domainname… unless you let the front-end handle setting the cookie